# enumeration for reference variable in Java

Tags: java

I am learning reference variables. If I have two classes: let’s say one is Person and the other is Minnesotan which extends Person class. The Person class is abstract. In the Person class, there is a reference variable called Gender which can be female, male and others. How can I write the reference variable Gender which has enumeration? how the reference variable can be extended in child class? Sorry if it is duplicate question and thank you in advance for your help.

```
public abstract class Person{
   public static Gender gender;
   class Gender{

   }
   public enum Gender{
       female,male,others;
   }
}
public class Minnesotan extends Person{
    public Minnesotan(Gender gender){
        super(gender);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What exactly do you want to happen there? Also, I think the `gender` variable in Person should not be static, as it belongs to each instance of the class.

Comment: First of all, remove that `Gender` class.

Comment: Second of all, outside `Person`, the `Gender` enum should be addressed as `Person.Gender`.

Comment: Is Person.Gender a reference variable? I don’t understand it. Can you explain it in detail? What if Person has to have Gender gender? Just like int num.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the enumeration,

```
public enum Gender{
 Male,
 Female
}
```

You can use references of that enumeration which will be of type `Gender` and can be either `Male` or `Female` like any other variables, for example,

```
Gender male = Gender.MALE;
if (male == Gender.MALE){
 System.out.println("Variable male has value Gender.MALE");
}else{
 System.out.println("Variable male has value Gender.FEMALE");
}
```

Now the `Person` class,

```
public abstract class Person{
 public Gender gender;
}
```

Static modifier is removed because each instance of `Person` should have each own gender.

And finally an actual implementation of `Person`, a `Minessotan`,

```
public class Minnesotan extends Person{
 public Minnesotan(Gender gender){
     this.gender = gender;
 }
}
```

In order to create a `Minnesotan`, which is a `Person`, you must provide it's gender, which is of type `Gender`. That's it.